# Php convert associative numeric array to normal array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

so I have this array:

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => "2020-06-01"
  1 => "2020-06-02"
  2 => "2020-06-03"
]
```

and I want to transform it into this:

```
["2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03"]
```

How can I do this? I know that maybe it's easy but I can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no different

Comment: ...or are you asking how to encode it into json?

Comment: It's already a normal array but when you use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` it shows with an index of the array elements.

Comment: Alright, now I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Or they could just not do anything at all, which would be a much better answer.

Comment: Maybe, his array has gaps between numeric array keys. My answer fix this and reset array keys.

Comment: _"Maybe, his array has gaps between numeric array keys"_ - They have posted their array in the question and there are no gaps. This answer is completely pointless and will only add extra overhead for no reason what so ever. And if there were a gap, then `(array) $array` would still give you the exact same array, gap and all.

Comment: _"They have posted their array in the question and there are no gaps"_ his array has 42 elements, but he display three elements only. We don't know that his array do not have gaps.

Comment: Fair enough, but `(array) $array` would still not solve that. And the OP hasn't mentioned anything about the indexes having gaps. If that's the case, the question would be off-topic since they haven't told us anything about the issue.